# PHP form remembers the previous information

Tags: php

I have a PHP form script which uses mail function. basically you write your email and the email to want to send the recommendation on the page to, and click send.

Here is the problem, once you have sent the recommendation, you can send it again, this time by refreshing the same page!

How can I make script to not remember the previous entered information by same user? flush() or something else. The script is placed in the middle of the page so I don't want the page stop executing after this php form.

Edit:
Thank you guys for your answeres, is there any script so I can use for for storing/validating IPs with help of mysql? or just a "plain text database"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

This is the web browser, not the form, that's causing this behaviour - when you refresh a page that was the result of a form submission, most browsers will offer to resubmit the data.

The usual "fix" is to submit the data to an intermediate page, then redirect the person back to the page they were viewing - that way they'd have to go back one page as well as refresh AND clicking "yes, I want to resubmit the data".

For completeness, consider only allowing a particular ip to use the "send to friend" function once per x seconds/minutes by tracking an IP's last use in a database.

For extra thoroughness, prevent a given recipient being told about a page more than once a day, or something.

Answer (score 0):

Two different things you might experience:

The fact that when you go to your form the information entered previously is remebered. That is typically a function of the webbrowser (and/or the plugings installed) and not so much a problem of your script/form. That is a similar function to how your browser might remeber login credentials for you.

Typically that is not much of an issue, but you could prevent that by generating unique names for your input fields each time the form is loaded.

```
<input type=text name=email lenght=40>...
```

then becomes

```
<inut type=hidden uniqueID=$something>
<input type=text name=email-$something lenght=40>...
```

and then use the uniqueID in your form processor to reconstruct all other field names when processing the form.

Your second problem is simply that your form processor allows the same content to be processed twice or more. A common problem with common fixes.

A traditional strategy was to redirect the browser to a succes/error page after processing the form contents, which can be reloaded without any penalty. form --> formhandler page (PHP) processes form contents and sends http redirect --> success/error page.

Or more common nowadays, store the above uniqueID of the form (e.g. in a database) and refuse to process a second time.